# dropdown value changed by javascript is not coming in codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a dropdown list whose value is changed based on other controls in the UI using javascript.

I used the following code to change the dropdown list,
`document.getElementById("ddlchkStsID").options[2].selected = true;
 document.getElementById("ddlchkStsID").value = "3";`

But in the code-behind, the `ddlchkStsID.SelectedValue` is still coming as first option's value.

This the control in aspx page.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlchkStsID"  runat="server" TabIndex="10"  CssClass="meta">
 <asp:ListItem Text="TBD" Value="1" />
 <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="2" />
 <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="3" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Could someone help me how to get the changed value in the code-behind.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where in the code behind are you checking the value? You may be checking it before the form values have been parsed...

Comment: Are you binding the dropdown in the `Page_Load` event without checking for `IsPostBack`?

Comment: Could you post a simple example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Not sure if i can post a .net code in jsFiddle. In the code behind, once it enters the page_load, i did a Response.Write(ddlchkStsID.SelectedValue.ToString()); It gave the first option's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the control is running at the server, you should be referencing the control using the ClientID, like this:

```
document.getElementById("<%=ddlchkStsID.ClientID%>").options[2].selected = true;
```

Is your JavaScript code actually working?

Comment: Yes. The client id generated is same as the ID. The dropdown changes to NO in front end. But in the code-behind the value is coming as 1.